# Удаление значений в многомерном массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

```
array ('0' => array ('cityID'=>1)
 '1' => array ('cityID'=>2)
 '2' => array ('cityID'=>3)
 '3' => array ('cityID'=>1)
 '4' => array ('cityID'=>2)
 '5' => array ('cityID'=>2))
```

Как удалить повторяющиеся элементы? На ум кроме array_unique ничего не приходит, но он, зараза, работает с одномерными массивами только (((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что вы не пробовали искать. Даже в мануалах, [есть пример](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php#116302) по вашей теме. Или такой короткий вариант:

```
$unique_arr = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $arr)));
```

Comment: Побывал ошибка 
`Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in /filiales/views/widget.php on line 56

array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $items)))`

Comment: а вообще спасибо на наводку там и не подумал посмотреть.

Comment: @ОлегКосарев, [тестируем на вашем массиве](http://ideone.com/ySYVCH). Как видите, всё работает. Скорее всего, что вы не всё в вопросе указали.